Banno External Application returning 401 error
Around the 13th or 14th of November our external application stopped authorizing requests. We hadn't changed anything on our side with the key or associated user.
I've since added a new public and private key but am still receiving a 401 error - what are some next steps we can take to identify the issue here?
Thanks!

You mentioned an associated user - can you confirm that you are using the Admin API? Secondarily, it would be helpful to have a x-request-id for one of your 401 requests.

Thank you for your response.
x-request-id:
c593dcb7d22142bee046237f576ae2a9
I am indeed using the admin API.

The request id you shared, it looks like the request is missing HTTP headers - where you would normally expect an authorization header or cookie.
I also see this request is from HTTPie so there could be some discrepancies - do you have a x-request-id from your code?

Long story short I don't have the ability to give you the x-request-id from the code. That request id was sent with the jwt that was given back from the auth api. Is there anything else I can give you on this?
Given the authentication method, that jwt should give me access to everything my associated user has access to.

Even using the client credentials helper repo it gives me a 401 error. I loaded up the client credentials helper to debug and it's giving me the error "invalid client".

Here's the headers for that:
date: [ 'Wed, 20 Nov 2024 17:19:05 GMT' ],     'content-type': [ 'application/json; charset=utf-8' ],     'content-length': [ '77' ],     connection: [ 'keep-alive' ],     'x-request-id': [ '86c70ba0f2320b9ffbb644cb6f88043f' ],     'x-b3-traceid': [ '9474b12b3f5d804bd271a0f239d695a9' ],     'x-b3-spanid': [ '990bf4624556f9a1' ],     'x-b3-sampled': [ '1' ],     traceparent: [ '00-9474b12b3f5d804bd271a0f239d695a9-990bf4624556f9a1-01' ],     'access-control-allow-origin': [ '*' ],     'cache-control': [ 'no-store' ],

Thanks for sharing these, still looking into it!

Hi Sam, I wanted to follow up and see if you had seen what I may be doing wrong here.
